# Unwanted attributes in form output-jQuery/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I append a jQuery ajax response into a php form select box.

```
<select name="adSizeFractional" id="fractionalads-list" >
               <option value="">---Select---</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Ajax Response:

```
var fractionalads = "<option value="+v.ad_size_fractional+">"+v.ad_size_fractional+"</option>";
                $(fractionalads).appendTo('#fractionalads-list');
```

Expected result:

```
<select>
  <option value="" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
  <option value="2/3 Page">2/3 Page</option>
  <option value="1/2 Page">1/2 Page</option>
  <option value="1/3 Page">1/3 Page</option>
</select>
```

Actual Result:(Error)

```
<select>
  <option value="" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
  <option value="2/3" page="">2/3 Page</option>
  <option value="1/2" page="">1/2 Page</option>
  <option value="1/3" page="">1/3 Page</option>
</select>
```

Why am I getting unwanted parameters in the form output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value attribute is not quoted, for attributes that are not quoted a space will terminate it, so quote your attribute

```
var fractionalads = "<option value=\""+v.ad_size_fractional+"\">"+v.ad_size_fractional+"</option>";
```

You should also html encode it

```
var fractionalads = "<option value=\""+htmlspecialchars(v.ad_size_fractional)+"\">"+htmlspecialchars(v.ad_size_fractional)+"</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

put quotes around value attribute

```
var fractionalads = "<option value='"+v.ad_size_fractional+"'>"+v.ad_size_fractional+"</option>";
                $(fractionalads).appendTo('#fractionalads-list');
```